# Почему в сущностях вместо примитивов используют классы-оболочки?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

Видел очень много примеров создания сущностей, но почему-то всегда вместо любых числовых значений используют не примитивы, а классы-оболочки. Например, вот так выглядит `ID` в сущности, которую я увидел в одном примере:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

И вот вопрос, почему используют именно `Long`, а не `long`? Это ведь наоборот хуже, так как будет выполняться авто-упаковка и распаковка, разве нет? Причем такое используют не только в поле `ID`, но и в других числовых типах. В этом есть какой-то смысл или это ошибка со стороны авторов подобных примеров?

Comment: Во-первых, если у вас поле id может в БД принимать значение NULL, то каким образом вы это отразите в сущности с полем примитивного типа? Во-вторых, Hibernate всё равно под капотом работает только со ссылочными типами, так что упаковки вам не избежать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Окей, насчет числовых типов понял, а что насчет ID, который почти всегда является первичным ключом и не может принимать null? Для него можно использовать примитивный тип?

Comment: Можете использовать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev понял, спасибо